# How to redirect/refresh the page after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After an AJAX call, I make an update on a PHP file, but I'm not sure, once the request is finished, what is the better way, if a PHP header location on the page who refresh the page where I'm from, or in the AJAX.done refresh the page.

Comment: If you're going to refresh the page, why use ajax, just do a form submit instead. Also, when using ajax, setting a PHP header wouldn't really work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you are doing Ajax query to other page, then `header("location: ...")` won't work as it can not refresh current page.
2. If you are making an Ajax request to the same page, don't do that. Instead submit the form the old school way.
3. If you are making an Ajax request to other page that does something essential for you and then you want to refresh the current page then use the given JavaScript code in AJAX.done.

If you want to preserve cache and reload(soft reload) which is a better way, use:

```
location.reload(false);
```

However If you have requirement to clear cache and reload(hard reload), use:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Hope this helps.

You can find more detail about `location.reload` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Comment: while this is correct and explains the solution, it's not preferred to cite [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/), use reliable sources instead like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)

Comment: @code-jaff thank you for suggestion. I changed the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a little noob about PHP and AJAX, and I just really want to know the best way to do that I need. Now to work ;)

Comment: And don't use location.reload(), it forces a full reload in Firefox (maybe others?) regardless of that parameter, you can just set the location = location; that will respect cached resources.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refresh the whole page then don't even use an ajax request, submit your form, and php redirect will be fine.

If you want to refresh a part of the page (for instance the content of a `div`), then you should do it client-side (in `Ajax.done`)